# Exporting jar files with passable arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, args

I'm trying to export a java program via eclipse but I'm having some problems:

I wan to be able to run it via command line and pass arguments to it, specifically the location of the properties file.

I've tried exporting it as a runnable jar file using main as the launch configuration, and also using another run configuration where arguments are passed at run time.

```
public static String currentStatus;
public static String filename = "etc/ryanair.properties";   
public boolean isDuplicate = true;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    String file = args[0];
    Properties config = new Properties();       
    config.load(new FileInputStream(file));

    System.out.println("====================BEGIN=======================");
    HtmlParser htmlparse = new HtmlParser(config);

    List<String> list = htmlparse.parse();  

    debug(list);
```

Basically I want to pass the location of the properties file ie `etc/ryanair.properties` but I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
           etc/ryanair.properties (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at com.beezer.twitter.traffic.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Funnily enough, If I use the variable `filename` instead of `file` where I don't need to pass arguments I am getting the same error.

I can run them fine within eclipse either with the file location as a fixed variable or as passed in with a run configuration but not via command line.

The `etc` folder is located as a sub directory of the `src` folder in eclipse.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you running the command line from? It is probably not the same location as Eclipse runs the jar from.

Comment: I'm running terminal in the same folder as the jar file is stored in ie /Projects/Ryanair/

Answer (score 0):

In your code , it will look for the file ryanair.properties in etc/ folder. And this etc folder should in your **current** path instead of your .jar's folder

Maybe you would like make the property file in your .jar file , you should make the property file as your resource file (in eclipse , right click the file , build path -> add to build path), and then use `HtmlParser.class.getResource("/ryanair.properties").getPath()` to get the file name. Take care of the root path of the resource.

about **current** path , which is the *current* path ? In linux , you may use `pwd` , in windows , you may use `echo %cd%` .

Comment: Correction, the etc folder is a root folder of the program, ie myproject/etc same root as the /src and /lib folder. Basically I want to build one program that will return different results based on the properties file passed in on run time ie, different airlines etc...

Comment: @mcgowan.b so...you may hope to make this etc/ folder outside of the jar file ? Relative path may not a good idea. Again , **current** location is base on where are you call the .jar